# How to find indices of change based on two vectors r

Tags: r

I have two vectors which contain indices which look like

```
index A  index B
   1        1
   1        1
   1        1
   1        2
   1        2
   2        1
   2        1
```

Now, I want to find the length of each combination between index A and index B. So, in my example there are three unique combinations for index A and index B and I want to get back 3, 2, 2 in a vector. Does anyone know how to this without a for loop?

EDIT:
So, in this example there are three unique combinations (1 1, 1 2 and 2 1) for which the there are 3 of combination 1 1, 2 of 1 2 and 2 of 2 1. Therefore, I want to return 3, 2, 2

Comment: 3 is for unique combination. What does the other two 2's denote?

Comment: the first 3 is for the number of 1 1, the other 2's are for the  number of combinations 1 2 and 2 1

Comment: so these are the frequencies of the number of unique combinations?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could paste the vectors together and call `rle`

```
rle(do.call(paste0, dat))$lengths
# [1] 3 2 2
```

If you need the result as a `data.frame`, do

```
as.data.frame(unclass(rle(do.call(paste0, dat))))
#  lengths values
#1       3     11
#2       2     12
#3       2     21
```

**data**

```
text <- "indexA  indexB
   1        1
   1        1
   1        1
   1        2
   1        2
   2        1
   2        1"

dat <- read.table(text = text, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want:

```r
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(index_A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                 index_B = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1))
count(df, vars = c("index_A", "index_B"))
#>   index_A index_B freq
#> 1       1       1    3
#> 2       1       2    2
#> 3       2       1    2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I got this from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/121088/240581).

Answer (score 3):

In `base R`, we can use `table`

```
as.data.frame(table(dat))
```

Comment: It's super cool, but I get an additional row of `2 2` with frequency 0.

Comment: @yarnabrina `table(dat)` gives a format where it looks for all the combinations.  If some of them are not there, it is provided 0.  if it is of no interest `subset(as.data.frame(table(dat)), Freq > 0)`

Answer (score 2):

This is somehow hacky:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Combined=paste0(`index A`,"_",`index B`)) %>% 
  group_by(Combined) %>% 
  summarise(n=n())
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Combined     n
  <chr>    <int>
1 1_1          3
2 1_2          2
3 2_1          2
```

Can actually just do:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(`index A`,`index B`) %>% 
  summarise(n=n())
```

Adding `tidyr` `unite` as suggested by @kath

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  unite(new_col,`index A`,`index B`,sep="_") %>% 
  add_count(new_col) %>% 
  unique()
```

Data:

```
df<-read.table(text="index A  index B
   1        1
               1        1
               1        1
               1        2
               1        2
               2        1
               2        1",header=T,as.is=T,fill=T)
df<-df[,1:2]
names(df)<-c("index A","index B")
```

Comment: You could replace the `mutate` with `unite()` and the `summarise` by `count()`...

Comment: @kath I first tried with `unite` but it seems it needs character data.

Comment: Strange, this works for me: `unite(df, new_col, `index A`, `index B`, sep = "_")`

Comment: @kath I've added this option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
count(dat,!!!dat)$n
# [1] 3 2 2
```